# How to code result of word search to count number of occurence of word

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to count the number of occurrences of words from a list. I need the result to be `(word, # of occurrence)` however I keep getting `(word, 1) (word, 2) (word,3)`, when it should be giving me `(word,3)`.

All the variables of `library`, `document`, and `dictionary` are defined in another area.

I believe my code is 99% correct but the result is not doing what I need it to.

```py
def (word_search) : 
    results = [] 

    search_word = dictionary [0]

    for search_word in dictionary: 

    count = 0 

    for document in library: 

       for word in document: 

          if search_word == word : 

            count = count + 1

            results.append((word,count)) 

     return (results)
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and desired output as well to reproduce the problem you are having.

Comment: input = "sad"
output = search(input) 
print(output)

Comment: Please provide input sample what does word_search, dictionary and library contain?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `results` is a list of tuples and you keep appending values to it whenever you find a new word occurrence.  `return (results[-1])` should work, but there is a simpler way to write this function, without the use of a list. I'll let you figure it out since you're still learning :)

Comment: Thanks for this. However, i need to return all the words in the search and when i do that its only returning one of the words. how can i edit to return all the words? i've been stuck for a while now!

Comment: to clarify its giving me one of the words and the total number of occurrences, but again i need to return all the words in the list and number of occurrences, if that makes sense? thanks for the assist!

Comment: just add word and its count in dictionary instead of list add word as key and its count as a value in dictionary

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to ident after the loop:

```
results = [] 

search_word = dictionary [0]

for search_word in dictionary: 

   count = 0 

   for document in library: 

      for word in document: 

         if search_word == word : 

           count = count + 1

           results.append((word,count)) 

 return (results)
```

Comment: HI, thanks for responding! Not sure i follow-indent where? all of my line are indented? just confused. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about trying out a solution that uses a Python `dict` (different from your variable dictionary)? In fact, there's a really nifty version of the python dict provided by Python called a `defaultdict` that can be initialised to a specific value if a key does not exist.

You could code something out like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def (word_search) : 
    results = defaultdict(int) # Make the dict use integers as the default entry value, set it to 0 if key does not exist

    search_word = dictionary [0]

    for search_word in dictionary: 

       for document in library: 

           for word in document: 

               if search_word == word : 

                   results[word] += 1 # Increment the count for the matched word


    return results.items() # Return the counts as a set of tuples
```

This would produce a set of tuples containing the count of each word!

Note: I fixed the indentation of the for loops too, in case that was causing the issue

---

Additionally, to improve efficiency, you could produce a count of all words and simply retrieve the counts of your search words at the end, thereby reducing the complexity from O(n^3) to O(n^2):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def (word_search) : 
    counts = defaultdict(int) # Make the dict use integers as the default entry value, set it to 0 if key does not exist
    for document in library: 

       for word in document: 

           counts[word] += 1 # Increment the count the given word

    # Loop through and extract just the counts of the words you're interested in
    results = []

    for search_word in dictionary: 
        results.append((search_word, counts[search_word]))

    return results
```

This should reduce your runtime significantly if your documents are very large!

Answer (score 0):

This might help you-

```
   str='bob sam jeff jeff bob jeff'
    x={}
    for i in str.split():
        if i in x.keys():
            x[i]+=1
        else:
            x[i]=1
    print (x)
```

Output

```
{'bob': 2, 'sam': 1, 'jeff': 3}
```